# How to increase the efficiency when running multiple nodejs application using docker compose

Tags: node.js, multithreading, docker, docker-compose, pm2

My current nodejs application using docker-compose(9 nodejs containers) looks like this:

```yaml
version: "3.8"
  event:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: ./docker/event.Dockerfile

  map:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: ./docker/mapper.Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - event

  account:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: ./docker/account.Dockerfile

  market:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: ./docker/market.Dockerfile
and 5 more...
```

Each of the nodejs contains around 20% of CPU-intensive workload and 80% of IO-intensive workload(including HTTP requests, listen to websocket, and database CRUD operation), they communicate through a database since nodejs is single-threaded, running 9 node applications at the same time uses up many memories(there should be a lot different than using one CPU to only run single container).

Is there any solution to change it to multi-thread/multi-processing, or another solution to increase the efficiency?

Comment: Node is normally single-threaded but heavily callback-oriented, so if you're I/O bound you should still be able to do other work while you're waiting for things like the database to complete.  It doesn't seem like the question you're asking is that specific to Docker.  If you just ran `node market.js` and `node account.js` together, would you see the same memory utilization?  Can you include some more details about why you think resource utilization is higher than you would expect, and what solutions you've tried so far?